No subject alternative DNS name matching found
Trying to make callout to an authentication provider and get the access token which I would be using in the consecutive callout with another endpoint. Was working fine Initially with all the endpoint URL's, Client Id, secret hardcoded in apex callout. But later on receiving the  No subject alternative DNS name matching found error while making callout. Not sure what is causing that issue suddenly. is it because of enabling enhanced domain in salesforce org? If so can this error be avoided by trying with Named credentials instead of hardcoded urls, clientid and clientsecret?

Does this answer your question? Salesforce Certificate Exception: No subject alternative DNS name matching found

^^^ 2014 but still the right answer
